# Vue is extremely slow to compile this HTML template in dev mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using a template app setup that I bootstrapped with vue CLI. I have one component that has 20 nested `div` tags. Compiling such a component in dev mode takes around 10 seconds. The deeper I nest the html elements the longer it takes and the time grows exponentially.

Is this behaviour normal? Is there a way to improve compilation time?

Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/dmitrybelyakov/ed64145624f42188372500018671eb0f

Comment: If you're using Prettier, here is your solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752427/building-deeply-nested-html-with-vue-cli-takes-forever
btw: Using 10 or more `div`s is a good sign to start putting some stuff in independent components.

Comment: @BennettDams amazing! I wasn't using prettier, but vue-loader's template compiler was. And this is exactly the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Since you have your answer you should answer your own question.

Comment: @SimonHyll not sure what you mean here. Shall I copy what Bennett said into an answer and accept it?

Comment: Basically, yea. Well, technically I guess he could also do it, but in case he doesn't do it you should answer your own question with his answer. StackOverflow wants questions to have answers so that other people finding this page will easily be able to find their answer, they don't care who answers. In fact they support you asking and answering your own question in case you just wanna share information with people.

Comment: @SimonHyll ok, cool, I didn't know that! Answered and accepted now. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question here: following [the link to this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752427/building-deeply-nested-html-with-vue-cli-takes-forever) by Bennett Dams, some people already investigated this, and there is an issue with `prettier` library that gets used internally by `vue-loader`, specifically their template compiler utils. The issue has been reported to prettier team [here](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/1250) and [there](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/4672), but it hasn't been fixed as of yet.

Because of that, vue template compiler comes with this issue out of the box. So if you nest ~30 html elements you can basically halt your compiler (only happens in dev mode).

Same goes for when you have less nested (~4-5) levels elements, but a few of them, in which case compilation gets progressively slower and reload/inject time suffers which makes waiting for your component to reload a pain.

I have reported this issue to `vue-loader` team here [#1426](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1426) asking for a config option to disable use of prettier, so hopefully it will get looked at.

**UPDATE:** this should now be fixed in `vue-loader` via `prettify` config option that was added: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1426

**OLD SOLUTION:**

For the moment though, the only fix is to edit `node_modules/@vue/component-compiler-utils/dis/compileTemplate.js` to comment out the line (should be around line 97) like so:

```
//code = prettier.format(code, { semi: false, parser: 'babylon' });
```