# npm run serve hangs forever vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm trying to port HTML template to `.vue` files. I know there's known problem with deeply nested DOM [like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752427/building-deeply-nested-html-with-vue-cli-takes-forever), but my `vue.config.js` already looks like that:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    const vueRule = config.module.rule('vue');
    vueRule.uses.clear();
    const vueLoader = vueRule.use('vue-loader').loader('vue-loader');
    vueLoader.options({
      prettify: false,
    });
  },
};
```

`npm run serve` hangs on 22% forever and it looks like that:

```
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
 22% building 106/110 modules 4 active ...bout.vue?vue&type=template&id=039c5b43&
```

While `NODE_ENV=production npm run serve` runs just fine.

Here's my whole `About.vue` file which hangs on render:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>About us</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="Destino project">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="plugins/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/about_styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/about_responsive.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="super_container">

    <!-- Header -->

    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="header_container d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">

                        <!-- Logo -->
                        <div class="logo_container">
                            <div class="logo">
                                <div>destino</div>
                                <div>travel agency</div>
                                <div class="logo_image"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Main Navigation -->
                        <nav class="main_nav ml-auto">
                            <ul class="main_nav_list">
                                <li class="main_nav_item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="main_nav_item active"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                                <li class="main_nav_item"><a href="offers.html">Offers</a></li>
                                <li class="main_nav_item"><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
                                <li class="main_nav_item"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>

                        <!-- Search -->
                        <div class="search">
                            <form action="#" class="search_form">
                                <input type="search" name="search_input" class="search_input ctrl_class" required="required" placeholder="Keyword">
                                <button type="submit" class="search_button ml-auto ctrl_class"><img src="images/search.png" alt=""></button>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Hamburger -->
                        <div class="hamburger ml-auto"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Menu -->

    <div class="menu_container menu_mm">

        <!-- Menu Close Button -->
        <div class="menu_close_container">
            <div class="menu_close"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Menu Items -->
        <div class="menu_inner menu_mm">
            <div class="menu menu_mm">
                <div class="menu_search_form_container">
                    <form action="#" id="menu_search_form">
                        <input type="search" class="menu_search_input menu_mm">
                        <button id="menu_search_submit" class="menu_search_submit" type="submit"><img src="images/search_2.png" alt=""></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <ul class="menu_list menu_mm">
                    <li class="menu_item menu_mm"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item menu_mm"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item menu_mm"><a href="offers.html">Offers</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item menu_mm"><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item menu_mm"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Menu Social -->

                <div class="menu_social_container menu_mm">
                    <ul class="menu_social menu_mm">
                        <li class="menu_social_item menu_mm"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="menu_social_item menu_mm"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="menu_social_item menu_mm"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="menu_social_item menu_mm"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="menu_social_item menu_mm"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="menu_copyright menu_mm">Colorlib All rights reserved</div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Home -->

    <div class="home">
        <!-- Image by https://unsplash.com/@peecho -->
        <div class="home_background parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="images/about_background.jpg" data-speed="0.8"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="home_content">
                        <div class="home_content_inner">
                            <div class="home_title">About us</div>
                            <div class="home_breadcrumbs">
                                <ul class="home_breadcrumbs_list">
                                    <li class="home_breadcrumb"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                    <li class="home_breadcrumb">About us</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Find Form -->

    <div class="find">
        <!-- Image by https://unsplash.com/@garciasaldana_ -->
        <div class="find_background_container prlx_parent">
            <div class="find_background prlx" style="background-image:url(images/find.jpg)"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="find_background parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="images/find.jpg" data-speed="0.8"></div> -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="find_title text-center">Find the Adventure of a lifetime</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="find_form_container">
                        <form action="#" id="find_form" class="find_form d-flex flex-md-row flex-column align-items-md-center align-items-start justify-content-md-between justify-content-start flex-wrap">
                            <div class="find_item">
                                <div>Destination:</div>
                                <input type="text" class="destination find_input" required="required" placeholder="Keyword here">
                            </div>
                            <div class="find_item">
                                <div>Adventure type:</div>
                                <select name="adventure" id="adventure" class="dropdown_item_select find_input">
                                    <option>Categories</option>
                                    <option>Categories</option>
                                    <option>Categories</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="find_item">
                                <div>Min price</div>
                                <select name="min_price" id="min_price" class="dropdown_item_select find_input">
                                    <option>&nbsp;</option>
                                    <option>Price</option>
                                    <option>Price</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="find_item">
                                <div>Max price</div>
                                <select name="max_price" id="max_price" class="dropdown_item_select find_input">
                                    <option>&nbsp;</option>
                                    <option>Price</option>
                                    <option>Price</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <button class="button find_button">Find</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- About -->

    <div class="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="section_title text-center">
                        <h2>We are an award winning Agency</h2>
                        <div>take a look at our story</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row about_row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 about_col order-lg-1 order-2">
                    <div class="about_content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce fringilla lectus nec diam auctor, ut fringilla diam sagittis. Quisque vel est id justo faucibus dapibus id a nibh. Aenean suscipit consequat lacus, sit amet mollis nulla. Morbi sagittis orci id lacus convallis tempus eget sit amet metus. Sed finibus, magna at euismod aliquet, enim justo vulputate lorem, sit amet elementum dolor eros sollicitudin dui. Sed ac magna mauris. Nullam lectus odio, viverra vel mi id, interdum imperdiet nulla. </p>
                        <div class="button about_button"><a href="#">Read More</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 about_col order-lg-2 order-1">
                    <div class="about_image">
                        <img src="images/about.jpg" alt="https://unsplash.com/@sanfrancisco">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Milestones -->

    <div class="milestones">
        <div class="milestones_background parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="images/fact_background.jpg" data-speed="0.8"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="section_title text-center">
                        <h2>Fun facts about our Agency</h2>
                        <div>take a look</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
                    <div class="milestones_text">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce fringilla lectus nec diam auctor, ut fringilla diam sagittis. Quisque vel est id justo faucibus dapibus id a nibh</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row milestones_container">

                <!-- Milestone -->
                <div class="col-lg-3 milestone_col">
                    <div class="milestone text-center">
                        <div class="milestone_icon"><img src="images/milestone_1.svg" alt=""></div>
                        <div class="milestone_counter" data-end-value="17">0</div>
                        <div class="milestone_text">Mountains Climbed</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Milestone -->
                <div class="col-lg-3 milestone_col">
                    <div class="milestone text-center">
                        <div class="milestone_icon"><img src="images/milestone_2.svg" alt=""></div>
                        <div class="milestone_counter" data-end-value="213">0</div>
                        <div class="milestone_text">Islands Visited</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Milestone -->
                <div class="col-lg-3 milestone_col">
                    <div class="milestone text-center">
                        <div class="milestone_icon"><img src="images/milestone_3.svg" alt=""></div>
                        <div class="milestone_counter" data-end-value="11923">0</div>
                        <div class="milestone_text">Photos Taken</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Milestone -->
                <div class="col-lg-3 milestone_col">
                    <div class="milestone text-center">
                        <div class="milestone_icon"><img src="images/milestone_4.svg" alt=""></div>
                        <div class="milestone_counter" data-end-value="15">0</div>
                        <div class="milestone_text">Cruises Organized</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Services -->

    <div class="services">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="section_title text-center">
                        <h2>Popular services that we offer</h2>
                        <div>take a look at these offers</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row icon_box_container">

                <!-- Icon Box -->
                <div class="col-lg-4 icon_box_col">
                    <div class="icon_box">
                        <div class="icon_box_image"><img src="images/service_1.svg" class="svg" alt="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/monkik"></div>
                        <div class="icon_box_title">Weekend trips</div>
                        <p class="icon_box_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adip iscing elit. Fusce fringilla lectus nec diam auctor, ut fringilla diam sagittis.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="icon_box_more">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Icon Box -->
                <div class="col-lg-4 icon_box_col">
                    <div class="icon_box">
                        <div class="icon_box_image"><img src="images/service_2.svg" class="svg" alt="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/monkik"></div>
                        <div class="icon_box_title">Fun leisure trips</div>
                        <p class="icon_box_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adip iscing elit. Fusce fringilla lectus nec diam auctor, ut fringilla diam sagittis.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="icon_box_more">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Icon Box -->
                <div class="col-lg-4 icon_box_col">
                    <div class="icon_box">
                        <div class="icon_box_image"><img src="images/service_3.svg" class="svg" alt="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/monkik"></div>
                        <div class="icon_box_title">Plane tickets</div>
                        <p class="icon_box_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adip iscing elit. Fusce fringilla lectus nec diam auctor, ut fringilla diam sagittis.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="icon_box_more">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Newsletter -->

    <div class="newsletter">
        <!-- Image by https://unsplash.com/@garciasaldana_ -->
        <div class="newsletter_background" style="background-image:url(images/newsletter.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
                    <div class="newsletter_content">
                        <div class="newsletter_title text-center">Subscribe to our Newsletter</div>
                        <div class="newsletter_form_container">
                            <form action="#" id="newsletter_form" class="newsletter_form">
                                <div class="d-flex flex-md-row flex-column align-content-center justify-content-between">
                                    <input type="email" id="newsletter_input" class="newsletter_input" placeholder="Your E-mail Address">
                                    <button type="submit" id="newsletter_button" class="newsletter_button">Subscribe</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <!-- Footer Column -->
                <div class="col-lg-4 footer_col">
                    <div class="footer_about">
                        <!-- Logo -->
                        <div class="logo_container">
                            <div class="logo">
                                <div>destino</div>
                                <div>travel agency</div>
                                <div class="logo_image"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer_about_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer pulvinar sed mauris eget tincidunt. Sed lectus nulla, tempor vel eleifend quis, tempus rut rum metus. Pellentesque ultricies enim eu quam fermentum hendrerit.</div>
                        <div class="copyright"><!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
Copyright &copy;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> All rights reserved | This template is made with <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> by <a href="https://colorlib.com" target="_blank">Colorlib</a>
<!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. --></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Footer Column -->
                <div class="col-lg-4 footer_col">
                    <div class="footer_latest">
                        <div class="footer_title">Latest News</div>
                        <div class="footer_latest_content">

                            <!-- Footer Latest Post -->
                            <div class="footer_latest_item">
                                <div class="footer_latest_image"><img src="images/latest_1.jpg" alt="https://unsplash.com/@peecho"></div>
                                <div class="footer_latest_item_content">
                                    <div class="footer_latest_item_title"><a href="news.html">Brazil Summer</a></div>
                                    <div class="footer_latest_item_date">Jan 09, 2018</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Footer Latest Post -->
                            <div class="footer_latest_item">
                                <div class="footer_latest_image"><img src="images/latest_2.jpg" alt="https://unsplash.com/@sanfrancisco"></div>
                                <div class="footer_latest_item_content">
                                    <div class="footer_latest_item_title"><a href="news.html">A perfect vacation</a></div>
                                    <div class="footer_latest_item_date">Jan 09, 2018</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Footer Column -->
                <div class="col-lg-4 footer_col">
                    <div class="tags footer_tags">
                        <div class="footer_title">Tags</div>
                        <ul class="tags_content d-flex flex-row flex-wrap align-items-start justify-content-start">
                            <li class="tag"><a href="#">travel</a></li>
                            <li class="tag"><a href="#">summer</a></li>
                            <li class="tag"><a href="#">cruise</a></li>
                            <li class="tag"><a href="#">beach</a></li>
                            <li class="tag"><a href="#">offer</a></li>
                            <li class="tag"><a href="#">vacation</a></li>
                            <li class="tag"><a href="#">trip</a></li>
                            <li class="tag"><a href="#">city break</a></li>
                            <li class="tag"><a href="#">adventure</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="styles/bootstrap4/popper.js"></script>
<script src="styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/greensock/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/greensock/TimelineMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/scrollmagic/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/greensock/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/greensock/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/easing/easing.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/parallax-js-master/parallax.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/about_custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'About',
}
</script>
```

Have you any idea why it runs fine in **production** mode while in **development** it can't? I've googled it very intensive, but I only know the issue with `prettify` which seems to be prevented in my case.

Comment: Do you find solution? I have exectly same problem.

Comment: @swasher I didn't. I've used `NODE_ENV=production` for most of the time. And once I've splitted most of my HTML code to separate components the problem disappeared. I think it's caused by deeply nested HTML elements but I don't have any evidence ;)

Comment: @qback might be also circular dependency