# Vue Dev Server not starting

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, vue-cli

I installed the vue-CLI node module. Then when I cd to my node project and type `npm run serve` it gets to around 27% building and stops. It also seems to be a different module that it stops building on. No error is thrown either, it just says 'building' but the percentage doesn't go up.

Has anyone else had this? I can't find a solution anywhere.

EDIT:

This is what the command line says when it stops building

```
INFO  Starting development server...
 20% building 89/99 modules 10 active ...odules\vue-hot-reload-api\dist\index.js
```

It seems to consistently be vut-hot-reload-api that causes it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752427/building-deeply-nested-html-with-vue-cli-takes-forever

Comment: Did you do `npm install`?

Comment: @connexo sorry yes i posted this after doing a fresh install of all my packages